# What is "import { obj, string } from 'grasshopper.data';"

Tags: javascript

There are many things I don't understand of my code:

1. I do not understand why the output prints "number"
2. What exactly do the `obj` and `string` in the import? (according to output)
3. Is there an alternative to use the import method? How could it be?

I am really sorry about fool question. I have studied only for two days.

```js
import { obj, string } from 'grasshopper.data';

for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    let letter = string[i];
    obj[letter] = i;
}

for (let property in obj) {
    console.log(property + ': ' + obj[property]);
}
```

Below you can find the code's actual output:

```sh
    h:0
    o:1
    n:2
    e:3
    s:4
    t:5

    g:0
    a:1
    t:2
    h:3
    e:4
    r:5

    w:0
    a:1
    t:2
    e:3
    r:4

    j:0
    u:1
    i:2
    c:3
    e:4
```

Comment: Sorry, it's totally unclear what you are asking about. Where and how are you running this code? What is `grasshopper.data`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Honest gather water juice?  lol, nice output text - actually the colon and number you are writing yourself in the upper iteration by doing: ` obj[letter] = i ` the `i` variable is a number therefore in the final output you are displaying the number

Answer (score -1):

```
import { obj, string } from 'grasshopper.data';
```

It means that you are getting the attributes 'obj' and 'string' from the object grasshopper.data.
JavaScript enables you to get just the attributes that you want from an object.

For example, suppose that I have the following object:

```
var myObj = {'name': "Foo Bar", 'nickname': "foo"}
```

And now I want to get just the nickname from myObj. To get that, I can use:

```
var {nickname} = myObj
```

That will give me `"foo"` as output.
You can also give a name for the variable that is created when you do that:

```
 var {nickname: myVariable} = myObj
```

Now you have a variable called myVariable with myObj.nickname as value.

Hope this helped you :)